# How to send a matrix to a thread function?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pointers, matrix

I have to create in C a program that is able to calculate the determinant of a random 3x3 matrix using the Sarrus method. I have to use one thread (Thread A) to compute blue diagonals, and a second thread (Thread B) to compute red ones. (See img https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQL1U.png )

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define m 3
#define n 3

typedef struct thread_params{
    int *data_matrix;
    int diag_result;
} thread_params;


void *diagA (void *params){
    thread_params *pp = (thread_params *) params;

    int **matrix_ptr = &pp->data_matrix;
    int diag = 0;

    diag = matrix_ptr[0][0] * matrix_ptr[1][1] * matrix_ptr[2][2] + matrix_ptr[0][1] * matrix_ptr[1][2] * matrix_ptr[2][0] + matrix_ptr[0][2] * matrix_ptr[1][0] * matrix_ptr[2][1];

    pp->diag_result = diag;
    return (void *) &pp->diag_result;
}

void *diagB (void *params){
    thread_params *pp = (thread_params *) params;

    int **matrix_ptr = &pp->data_matrix;
    int diag = 0;

    diag = matrix_ptr[2][0] * matrix_ptr[1][1] * matrix_ptr[0][2] + matrix_ptr[2][1] * matrix_ptr[1][2] * matrix_ptr[0][0] + matrix_ptr[2][2] * matrix_ptr[1][0] * matrix_ptr[0][1];

    pp->diag_result = diag;
    return (void *) &pp->diag_result;
}

int main(){

    // Create matrix
    int **matrix;
    int row;

    matrix = (int **) malloc(m * sizeof(int *));
    for (row = 0; row < m; row++){
        matrix[row] = (int *) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    }

    // Matrix initialization
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 10;
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }printf("\n");
    }

    // Thread creation
    pthread_t threadA_id;
    pthread_t threadB_id;

    int *threadA_returnValue;
    int *threadB_returnValue;

    thread_params threadA_args;
    thread_params threadB_args;

    threadA_args.data_matrix = &matrix[0][0];
    threadA_args.diag_result = 0;

    threadB_args.data_matrix = &matrix[0][0];
    threadB_args.diag_result = 0;


    pthread_create(&threadA_id, NULL, &diagA, &threadA_args);
    pthread_create(&threadB_id, NULL, &diagB, &threadB_args);

    pthread_join(threadA_id, (void **) &threadA_returnValue);
    pthread_join(threadB_id, (void **) &threadB_returnValue);

    // Print results
    printf("%d - %d = %d\n", *threadA_returnValue, *threadB_returnValue, *threadA_returnValue - *threadB_returnValue);

    return 0;
}
```

The main problem is that I don't know how to correctly send the random matrix as argument to the threads functions. I tried to utilize a struct with a pointer inside but in this way I'm able to sent to the thread function only the first row of my matrix and then, when I try to access the second row, a segmentation fault error is generated.

I think my error is caused by this type of assignation:

```
threadA_args.data_matrix = &matrix[0][0];
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `data_matrix` should be `int **`, not `int *`, and you should simply assign `= matrix`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli in this way I obtain the error  `initialization of int ** from incompatible pointer type int ***` on the line  `int **matrix_ptr = &pp->data_matrix;`

Comment: Well, since now you have an `int**` you don't need the `&` anymore there. Anyway my comment was just a quick observation, I don't know if that's the source of all the problems you might have. In general, if you have a matrix you pass it around using a double pointer.

Comment: Thank you it works now. I had to remove `&`